# remove case sensitive in mysql search

Tags: php, mysql

I am write a query for search like:

```
SELECT * from page where (UPPER(page_title) LIKE 'PRIYA%');
```

But in my database i have a multiple result of priya like `Priya_patel` ,`Priya_Patel` ,`Priya_d`
but the result was empty for this query.

My data in `page_title` field is:

```
Priya_patel, Priya_Patel,Priya_d_patel,Priya_yahoo,Priya_Mansi
```

Comment: Please edit the question to show the sample data and the table layout.

Answer (score 1):

For the table field "**page_title**" select **COLLATION** to '**utf8_unicode_ci**' or to some which is having **_ci** as suffix in it.

ci in '_ci' stands for Case Insensitive.

Then you execute the following query

```
SELECT * from page where page_title LIKE 'PRIYA%';
```

or

```
 SELECT * from page where page_title LIKE 'priya%';
```

or whatever ....

Comment: Anyways, OP has used `(UPPER(page_title)` so it will take care of case.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is perfectly working. Problem is somewhere else.

```
SELECT * from page where (UPPER(page_title) LIKE 'PRIYA%');
```

Check [DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/99d6b/1)

Comment: and the last one `)` for?

Comment: The extra parens shouldn't have anything to do with this.

Comment: @Log1c Thats what OP has already. We need to see the database schema. Might be OP is selecting wrong column.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is working correctly,

```
SELECT * FROM toto WHERE (UPPER( name ) LIKE  'PRIYA%')
```

also you can try like this to get the case insensitive result,

```
SELECT * FROM page WHERE LOWER(  `page_title` ) LIKE LOWER(  "PRIYA%" )
```